# Best way to make a DIV appear (slide out) on page load?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div box on a web page and I need a small div that looks like a tab, to appear behind the main box a second or two after the page loads. When the tab appears I want it to *slide* out, rather than fade in.

A similar example of what I'm looking for is on the wetransfer.com website:

[www.wetransfer.com/](https://www.wetransfer.com/)  (check the tabs on the left when the page loads)

What's the best way to implement this with jQuery?

Thanks for your time,

Darren

Comment: take a look at the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function provided by jquery

Comment: A [guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/) to get you started. Fire the slide from a DOM-ready callback. Another option would be to use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Ewq8u/ or http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Ewq8u/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code :

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
   $(".block").animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vikam, I'm going to use this but with .slideDown(). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this? It fires some animation when the whole page has loaded

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $('yourelement').animate({ left: '200'}, 'fast');
});
```